# Detecting a template function of a class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

Given

```
class A {
public:
    template <typename U, typename V, typename W>
    void foo (const U&, V*, const W*) const {}
    template <typename R, typename U, typename V, typename W>
    R bar (const U&, V*, const W*) const {return R{};}
};
```

we want a traits class that will determine if A has `foo` and `bar` with suitable arguments.  Detecting `foo` is working, but I'm stuck trying to detect `bar` because of its template return type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
    template <typename U, typename V, typename W>
    void foo (const U&, V*, const W*) const {}
    template <typename R, typename U, typename V, typename W>
    R bar (const U&, V*, const W*) const {return R{};}
};

template <typename...> struct voider {using type = void;};

template <typename... Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W, typename = void_t<T>>
struct HasFoo: std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W>
struct HasFoo<T, U, V, W,
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<const T&>().foo(std::declval<const U&>(), std::declval<V*>(), std::declval<const W*>()))>>
    : std::true_type {}; 

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W, typename = void_t<T>>
struct HasBar: std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W>
struct HasBar<T, U, V, W,
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<const T&>().bar(std::declval<const U&>(), std::declval<V*>(), std::declval<const W*>()))>>
    : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << HasFoo<A, int, bool, char>::value << '\n';  // true
    std::cout << HasBar<A, int, bool, char>::value << '\n';  // false (want it to be true)
}
```

How to fix `HasBar` so that the last output evaluates to true?

Comment: You are trying to detect whether `a.bar(u, v, w)` is a valid expression, with suitably declared variables `a`, `u`, `v` and `w`. Your trait correctly reports that it indeed is not; the caller must write, say, `a.bar<int>(u, v, w)`. Put another way: imagine that you made `HasBar` report `true` in this case - how do you plan to use it?

Comment: Ok, I tried `template <typename T, typename R, typename U, typename V, typename W>
struct HasBar<T, R, U, V, W,
 void_t<decltype(std::declval<const T&>().bar<R>(std::declval<const U&>(), std::declval<V*>(), std::declval<const W*>()))>>
 : std::true_type {};`.  It does not compile.

Comment: @prestokeys `std::declval<const T&>().template bar<R>`

Comment: Ah!  The disambiguator.  Ok, solved!